# read data with pyusb

Tags: python-3.x, usb, pyusb

I have a digital caliper and want to receave the output data via usb, with no result so far

Here is what I tried:

after reading the  docs [pyusb](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst)
I need to use`read()` function for this type of data.

so I need to find the correct endpoint address first

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0403, idProduct=0x6001)

ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================

       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN # Endpoint in

       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
```

The second parameter is the data payload (write) or the number of bytes to read (read)
Im not sure but I assume its `wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)`

for the time out argument I use the `Device.default_timeout` property as the operation timeout .

so I wrote a loop to wait for receaving data

```
import usb.core
import usb.util




dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x0403, idProduct=0x6001)

while True:
    ret = dev.read(0x81, 0x44 )
    print(ret)
```

and got a `raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 10060] Operation timed out`

What am I missing here?

Full Device Desription

```
DEVICE ID 0403:6001 on Bus 001 Address 007 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :    0x8 (8 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x0403
 idProduct              : 0x6001
 bcdDevice              :  0x400 Device 4.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 MAHR
 iProduct               :    0x2 16EXu
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 MAO74LCR
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 44 mA ===================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x20 (32 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0xa0 Bus Powered, Remote Wakeup
   bMaxPower            :   0x16 (44 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Vendor Specific ===========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xff
     bInterfaceProtocol :   0xff
     iInterface         :    0x2 16EXu
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
```

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? having the same troubles..

Comment: kind of, the device i had trouble with is connected via USB but the Signal is not transfered via the "USB Format" but send to the virtual Com Port, so I used PySerial to catch the signal, works fine so far

Comment: Hello, I think I am running to similar problem with a medical device, it transfers data to virtual Com port and not via USB Format. The device you have used for your testing has a baud rate defined for this transfer? and I have to replace it's driver with USB Cdc for it create a VCP, by default windows installs WinUsb driver when I connect the device. Do you have to do that as well?